# Delphi 11.3: strange issue with "GDI Scaling" + bsNone BorderStyle on secondary form, wrong screen coordinates with multiple monitor setup

Tags: delphi, scaling, gdi, dpi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm experiencing a weird issue when I set "DPI Awareness" mode in the project options to "GDI Scaling" with a secondary form, where, if I set its **BorderStyle to bsNone** and change its position **while the Main form is on another monitor** with different DPI scaling, the coordinates (within Monitor 1) are completely off. Let me explain my case and how to reproduce more clearly:

My setup (Windows 11)

- Monitor 1: 1920x1080, 100% scale (DPI)
- Monitor 3: 4K TV, cloned with Monitor 1
- Monitor 2: 1920x1200, 150% scale (DPI), to the right of Monitor 1

Case 1: I create Form2 (bsSizeable), Form1 is in either Monitor, I change Form2's position -> OK
Case 2: I create Form2 (bsNone), Form1 is in Monitor 1, I change Form2's position -> OK
Case 3: I create Form2 (bsNone), **-move Form1 to Monitor 2-**, then change Form2's position -> the position is completely wrong.

"Per Monitor v2" -> OK in all cases (different, unrelated issues, however)
"GDI Scaling" + bsSizeable (Form2) -> OK
"GDI Scaling" + bsNone (Form2) -> wrong position

[image: Case 1]
[image: Case 2]
[image: Case 3]

DPR

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2},
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles;

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Unit 1

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses Unit2;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Application);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Left := Screen.PrimaryMonitor.WorkareaRect.Left + 300;
  Form2.Top  := Screen.PrimaryMonitor.WorkareaRect.Top  + 300;
  Form1.Caption := Form2.Left.ToString + ' - ' + Form2.Top.ToString;
end;

end.
```

Form 1

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 312
  ClientWidth = 296
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  Position = poScreenCenter
  TextHeight = 15
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 185
    Height = 121
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 135
    Width = 185
    Height = 114
    Caption = 'Button2'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
end
```

Unit 2

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, ShellApi,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
  private
    procedure CreateParams(var Params : TCreateParams);  override;
  public
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.CreateParams(var Params : TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  With Params do begin
    ExStyle   := ExStyle or WS_EX_TOPMOST;
    WndParent := GetDesktopwindow;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Form 2

```
object Form2: TForm2
  Left = 100
  Top = 100
  AlphaBlendValue = 200
  BorderStyle = bsNone
  Caption = 'Form2'
  ClientHeight = 95
  ClientWidth = 201
  Color = 4227327
  TransparentColorValue = clGreen
  DefaultMonitor = dmPrimary
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  FormStyle = fsStayOnTop
  Position = poScreenCenter
  Visible = True
  TextHeight = 15
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 142
    Height = 37
    Caption = 'Hello World'
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -27
    Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: `Form2.Left := Screen.PrimaryMonitor.WorkareaRect.Left + 300;` looks suspicious - positions the form based on the work area of the Primary Monitor when it's on another monitor.

Comment: The primary monitor is always the same, no matter where the form is, but changing that to a fixed position has the same results.